# Java 10, IntellIJ не могу установить 10 programming language level

Tags: intellij-idea, java

Привет! Появилась у меня проблема с jdk 10 (18.3). Очень бы хотел узнать, что я забыл сделать, а за любой ответ скажу спасибо. Заключается в следующем:

После появления Java 10, я, собственно, захотел её установить.

Установил jdk 10, в cmd если пишу `java -version` пишет

> Java version "10" 2018-03-20, SE Runtime Environment 18.3.

В java project в intellIJ естественно, поставил jdk 10.

Хотел ознакомиться с "var". Пишу в intellIJ обычный код:

`var a = 5; 
var b = 10; 
var c = 10 + 5;`

Все слова var выделяются красным. Немного подумав и почитав, увидел, что у меня уровень языка программирования в настройках проекта стоит 9, а var для java появляется в 10. Но проблема в том, что 10 уровня у меня нету: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После головной боли, которой бы не возникло, если бы у меня было больше опыта работы с Java и intellIJ, я в сладких надеждах даже установил новый jre.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему 10 уровень не отображается? Буду очень благодарен каждому ответу.

Comment: Upd: забыл добавить, может это важно: Версия intellIJ не самая новая: 2017.3.5

Comment: слишком древняя сборка

Comment: Благодарю, Artem! На деле, всё оказалось довольно просто, но в голову почему-то не бросилось :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия оказалась слишком древней, спасибо Артёму Коновалову.